# using constant in a while loop (c)

Tags: c

I have the following c code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER 100;
#define MIN_NUMBER 10;

int main()
{
        printf("\nThis is a wonderful test for loops\n");

        int i = 12;
        while(i < MAX_NUMBER)
        {
                printf(" The value of i is %d \n", i);
                i += 10;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

when I compile, I get the following error message.

```
loop.c: In function ‘main’:
loop.c:11: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
```

But if replace the MAX_NUMBER in while loop, it compiles and runs smoothly. Please tell me how to use a constant in while loop.

Comment: Remove the ending semicolon from both `#define` lines.

Answer (score 2):

You defined your macros with a `;` at the end:

```
#define MAX_NUMBER 100;
#define MIN_NUMBER 10;
```

The `while` looks like this...

```
   while(i < 100;)
```

... and the compiler rightfully complains: expected `)` before `;`.

Remove the semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

DON'T PUT SEMICOLONS IN YOUR #defines!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER 100
#define MIN_NUMBER 10

int main()
{
        printf("\nThis is a wonderful test for loops\n");

        int i = 12;
        while(i < MAX_NUMBER)
        {
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove semicolons at end of following macros

```
#define MAX_NUMBER 100;
#define MIN_NUMBER 10;
```

It should be

```
#define MAX_NUMBER 100
#define MIN_NUMBER 10
```

Your code will be converted like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_NUMBER 100;
#define MIN_NUMBER 10;

int main()
{
        printf("\nThis is a wonderful test for loops\n");

        int i = 12;
        while(i < 100;)
        {
                printf(" The value of i is %d \n", i);
                i += 10;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Because of the semicolon in the while condition statement you are getting error.
While condition should be

```
  while(i < 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

As your code,the compliler "translate" it like this:

```
while(i < 100;)
```

Do you know how to modify the code?

Answer (score 0):

Check the syntax of the define keyword and it's usage once.

```
#define token [value]
```

if any statement preceded with # symbol, it need not be end with semi colon(;).